# Unable to use MyChart function

Tags: javascript, function, chart.js

I have got a function to update a chart in javascript.

Code:

```
    function updateChartAjaxCall(data1, data2)
    {
        //ajax call here 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'data.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {data1:data1,data2:data2},
            success:function(data){ 

                myChart.removeData();
                myChart.addData('newLabel', [23, 33, 4]);
            }, 
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log(thrownError);
            }, 
            complete: function(){
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }

$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var op1 = [];
            var op2 = [];

            let data_keys = Object.keys(data[0])
            console.log(data_keys)
            first = data_keys[0] //1st element
            second = data_keys[1] //2nd element

            for(var i in data) {
                op1.push(data[i][first])
                op2.push(data[i][second])

            }

         var chartdata = {
         labels: op1,
         datasets : [
             {
             label: 'SystemID and Apparent Power (VA)',
             backgroundColor: 'rgba(250, 50, 50, 0.4)',
             borderColor: 'rgba(500, 50, 50, 0.5)',
             hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(500, 30, 30, 0.2)',
             hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(500, 30, 30, 0.3)',
             data: op2
         } 
         ]
  };

  var ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');

  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartdata,
    options: {
    scales: {
       xAxes: [{
               ticks: {
                fontSize: 10
               }
              }],
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                fontSize: 10
            }
        }]
            }
         }
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    }
    });


});
```

Error I am getting:

```
app.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: myChart is not defined
at Object.success (app.js:11)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at y (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Can someone assist, why am I getting this error? I am using chartJS library. What am I missing?

I have updated my code to show the declaration of myChart
I need updateChartAjaxCall function global as I am calling it from another .html file to update `data1` and `data2`.

Comment: Where is your var myChart declared? The error suggests you haven't created the variable, and you do not show its creation in the code...

Comment: Have updated post now please see

Comment: Your var mychart is declared inside $(document).ready()
That means its not accessible from your function that its declared outside.

Comment: Just put a line at the top of your js file like this: var myChart;
And delete "var" from myChart = new Chart(ctx, {})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occur because in the scope of the metthod updateChartAjaxCall, myChart does not exist because your declared it inside the '$(document).ready(function(){' function

This should work

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}

function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
}

var myChart;

function updateChartAjaxCall(data1, data2) {
    //ajax call here 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'data.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            data1: data1,
            data2: data2
        },
        success: function (data) {

           removeData(myChart);
           addData(myChart, 'newLabel', [23, 33, 4]);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(thrownError);
        },
        complete: function () {}
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var op1 = [];
            var op2 = [];

            let data_keys = Object.keys(data[0])
            console.log(data_keys)
            first = data_keys[0] //1st element
            second = data_keys[1] //2nd element

            for (var i in data) {
                op1.push(data[i][first])
                op2.push(data[i][second])

            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: op1,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'SystemID and Apparent Power (VA)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(250, 50, 50, 0.4)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(500, 50, 50, 0.5)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(500, 30, 30, 0.2)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(500, 30, 30, 0.3)',
                    data: op2
                }]
            };

            var ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');

            myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartdata,
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                fontSize: 10
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                fontSize: 10
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });


});
```

You can also add the utils function to the prototype to use function from myChart

```
Chart.prototype.removeData = function() {
    this.data.labels.pop();
    this.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    this.update();
}

Chart.prototype.addData = function(label, data) {
    this.data.labels.push(label);
    this.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    this.update();
}
```

Comment: Now im getting `myChart.removeData is not a function` error ?

Comment: That's because the removeData function does not exist in the chartJs api, check this https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: But it does? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: No, ChartJs give you an an how to do the update but you need to add this function manually in your code, check my edit

Comment: Ok I did exactly that and I'm getting `myChart.removeData is not a function` ? lol

Comment: If you want to use 'myChart.removeData' instead of 'removeData(chart)' you need to add the remove function to the prototype, added to my last edit

Comment: ok thanks thats not returning any errors now, however my graph is not being replaced when i run this function in my other code.. different problem but thanks for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189212/discussion-between-danny-and-tristan-de-oliveira).